# Why my recycler view doesn't show the data?

Tags: android-recyclerview

I tried to upload some data in recycler view. The program doesn't show any error but the recycler view always stays empty after running the program.

Here is my xml code for layout design:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rc_view_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject_text"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="261dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_text"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="301dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FF0404" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classroom_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="238dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="115dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Model class:

```java
package com.example.schooltimetable;

public class RCModelClass {
    private String subject_text;
    private String time_text;
    private String classroom_text;
    private String teacher_text;

    RCModelClass(String subject_text, String time_text, String classroom_text, String teacher_text){
        this.subject_text = subject_text;
        this.time_text = time_text;
        this.classroom_text = classroom_text;
        this.teacher_text = teacher_text;
    }

    public String getSubject_text() {
        return subject_text;
    }

    public String getTime_text() {
        return time_text;
    }

    public String getClassroom_text() {
        return classroom_text;
    }

    public String getTeacher_text() {
        return teacher_text;
    }
}
```

Adapter class:

```java
public class RCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RCAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<RCModelClass> rcsubjectList;

    public RCAdapter (List<RCModelClass>rcsubjectList){this.rcsubjectList = rcsubjectList; }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RCAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_design, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RCAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String subject = rcsubjectList.get(position).getSubject_text();
        String time = rcsubjectList.get(position).getTime_text();
        String classroom = rcsubjectList.get(position).getClassroom_text();

        holder.setData(subject, time, classroom);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView subject_view;
        private TextView time_view;
        private TextView classroom_view;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            subject_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_text);
            time_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
            classroom_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classroom_text);
        }

        public void setData(String subject, String time, String classroom) {
            subject_view.setText(subject);
            time_view.setText(time);
            classroom_view.setText(classroom);
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    List<RCModelClass> rcsubjectList;
    RCAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initData();
    }

    private void initData() {
        rcsubjectList = new ArrayList<>();
        rcsubjectList.add(new RCModelClass("math", "12:05 - 12:50", "27B", "Person"));
        rcsubjectList.add(new RCModelClass("science", "13:05 - 13:50", "26B", "Person"));
        rcsubjectList.add(new RCModelClass("biology", "14:05 - 14:50", "22", "Person"));
        rcsubjectList.add(new RCModelClass("physics", "15:05 - 15:50", "11", "Person"));
        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.MainRecView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RCAdapter(rcsubjectList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Recycler view in main activity layout is called: `MainRecView`

What is wrong here? I tried all sort of things but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this code

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

why are you returning 0?
return the list size..

and let me make a suggestion ,
dont pass the list while initialising the adapter , just keep a list obj in the adapter and keep it empty at first..
and create a update method where you pass your list and call notifyDataSetChanged method in adapter only..

its like -
public class RCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RCAdapter.ViewHolder> {

```
private List<RCModelClass> rcsubjectList;

public RCAdapter (){rcsubjectList = new ArrayList()}

public void updateData(List<RCModelClass>rcsubjectList){this.rcsubjectList.clear();
    this.rcsubjectList.addAll(rcsubjectList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();}

@NonNull
@Override
public RCAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_design, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RCAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String subject = rcsubjectList.get(position).getSubject_text();
    String time = rcsubjectList.get(position).getTime_text();
    String classroom = rcsubjectList.get(position).getClassroom_text();

    holder.setData(subject, time, classroom);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rcsubjectList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView subject_view;
    private TextView time_view;
    private TextView classroom_view;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        subject_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_text);
        time_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
        classroom_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.classroom_text);
    }

    public void setData(String subject, String time, String classroom) {
        subject_view.setText(subject);
        time_view.setText(time);
        classroom_view.setText(classroom);
    }
}
```

}